# セルに貼り付けたURLのHTMLをログに展開したい

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-spreadsheet

[スクレイピング用ライブラリの使い方](https://so.sha-box.com/2022/08/gas-cheerio/)

上記サイトからCheerioライブラリを使用して、ログにホームページのHTML情報を出力したいのですが、うまくいきません

下記のコードは何が間違っているのでしょうか？

```
function textAndAddClass() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheetURL  =  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付け'), true);

    for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
        let URL = sheetURL.getRange('A' + i).getValue();
        const $ = cheerio.load(body)
        console.log($);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おそらくエラーメッセージが出力されているはずで、そこに原因も書いてあることと思います。質問のコードを見るかぎりですと、以下のような原因が考えられます。

- `body` という変数の定義が見当たらない
- そもそも HTML を取得するコードが無い
- `cheerio` は大文字で始まる `Cheerio` である可能性
  （これはライブラリの導入時の設定によります。Apps Script のデフォルトでは大文字始まりになっているようです）

以下は、これらを修正した例です（手元で動作確認できるようにシートの取得部分なども変更しています）。

```js
function test() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheetURL = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(), true);

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    try {
      let URL = sheetURL.getRange('A' + i).getValue();
      console.log("URL: ", URL);

      let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
      console.log("レスポンスコード", response.getResponseCode());

      let content = response.getContentText("utf-8");
      console.log("内容の長さ:", content.length);

      const $ = Cheerio.load(content);
      console.log("タイトル:", $("title").text());

      // for ループでなく、each メソッドを使用してもよいです
      for (let elm of $("h1")) {
        console.log("見出し:", $("h1").text());
      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.error("取得に失敗しました:", err);
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、ご回答いただけた場所で自分がどこを誤っていたのかわかりました。
手元で動作確認をしてみます